# save child class data of tab activity

Tags: android, android-widget

Suppose there are four child class of tab activity.I set a save button in tab activity class.
when application is open there show 1st child class layout.I work and press save button .then save this data into database.then I tap second child class.it show second layout .i work and press save button.I want to save data.!
[image]

How can I work on save button.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should check first:1 get the tab Id,buttonSave {if(tab==1){} ifif(tab==2){}}